# Problems with Displaying Binary Tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell

So, I have successfully managed to create a balanced binary tree however I am having trouble with trying to display it in the GHCi as a tree.

Currently the program is returning:

```
Node 1 (Node 2 (Node 3 Empty Empty) (Node 4 Empty Empty)) (Node 5 (Node 6 Empty Empty) (Node 7 Empty Empty))
```

However I would like to experiment with the code to make it print like this:

```
     1
    /  \
   2    5
  / \   /\
 3   4  6 7
```

I've seen a few answers using pretty print but I'm finding it very confusing to use.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: You might be interested in this site, which goes over many ways to lay out a drawing of a tree. http://billmill.org/pymag-trees/

Comment: Data.Tree has built in functions to show trees, although they are multiway, not binary.